# Does the size of a texture image impact the performance of texture fetching?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, textures, fragment-shader

Using OpenGL ES 2.0, does the size of the texture impact how long it takes to fetch from a texture?  I would think that it should be almost constant time to fetch a color.

Comment: By fetch, do you mean in the shader using a texture lookup function?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i mean.

Comment: Well, *"almost"* constant, like any other memory access. I would guess that a larger texture will cause texture accesses of neighbouring fragments to deviate by more texels and could thus cause the texture cahce to be not used as effectively. But other than those usual problems caused by any enlargement of memory, I cannot image another way the texture size could *directly* influence lookup speed (but I'm also not a GPU hardware architect).